# Converter data para timestamp do Unix

Tags: mysql, data, timestamp, unix

Tenho uma tabela num banco MySQL que possui um coluna data `VARCHAR`, tipo `20-09-2017` e preciso migrar essa coluna para uma coluna `bigint(8)` que usa o formato de data `timestamp` do Unix.

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-09-20 00:00:00')
```

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).

Se estiver em outro formato, aí tem que formatar antes:

```
STR_TO_DATE('20-09-2017', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/TimeStamp.sql).

Answer (score 1):

Segue a solução que eu utilizei.

Convertendo de string para data:

```
Update `tabela` 
set date = STR_TO_DATE(date_text, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Convertendo de data para unix timestamp:

```
Update `tabela`
set date_unix = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('date');
```

Comment: No caso, nota-se que a solução é justamente o que foi postado na outra resposta, é isso? Seria bom marcá-la como aceita para fechar a questão.

Comment: O problema é quando eu fiz a pergunta eu não tinha me registrado ainda.
Agora não consigo aceitar a resposta do Maniero. Sorry pelo BO.

Comment: Se for o caso, pode sinalizar para equipe do site mesclar suas postagens, caso seja possível que eles determinem as que são realmente suas. Desta forma acredito que você poderia receber a pontuação "perdida" de volta; quanto ao ocorrido, fique tranquila. Não há necessidade de pedir desculpas, foi apenas uma recomendação por uma questão de organização do site.